# Bluemix node.js doesn't like "=>"

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, box

I'm new to Bluemix and node.js. I'm creating a Bluemix app that integrates with Box, but the built in Box service uses out-of-date node.js support, and I'd like to use the most recent node.js Box SDK.

I'm including this line at the top of my code

```
    var BoxSDK = require('box-node-sdk');
```

But in processing this SDK, the log file throws an error on this line (line 191 of box-node-sdk/lib/api-request.js):

> this.stream.on('error', err => this.eventBus.emit('response', err));

The error is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>

What do I need to do to get Bluemix's node.js to recognize this (apparently new) syntax?

Comment: Run it through Babel first? As in https://babeljs.io/

Comment: What  version of node.js are you running?  `=>` is ES6 arrow syntax which requires a newer version of node.js (at least node 4.x for some support and node 6.x for full support).

Comment: @jfriend00 -- exactly. As I said, I'm new to both Bluemix and node.js, so I have no idea what version it's running. I see this in the log -- this might be indicating that it's running node 3.7? "IBM SDK for Node.js Buildpack v3.7-20160826-1101"

Comment: I should add that I'm modifying a sample Bluemix node.js app, and after some googling, I find the node.js version in the package.json file is as follows (unless I'm misinterpreting things...)
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.*"
  },

Answer (score 0):

After some further digging, I discovered [this page](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/nodejs/index.html#nodejs_runtime) in the Bluemix runtime documentation, which says:

> A node version should always be specified in the package.json file. If it is not, the latest node version will be used.

I removed the engines{} section from my package.json file to force it to use the latest node version, and I've gotten past this problem. (On to my next error...)

Thanks very much to [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00), who gave the crucial information that led me where I needed to go!